# Tinymce 6 can't initialize any plugins

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE 6. I had been using 4 but I'm trying to start from scratch since I couldn't get the upgrade to work.

I can get the editor to load but can't initialize any plugins. I did see this doc (https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/fixing-plugin-errors/) but couldn't find any answers there.  I can navigate to the link folder in plugins and the plugin file is there...

This is the error I get (with any plugin, but this happens to be link):

```
Failed to initialize plugin: link TypeError: a.addButton is not a function
```

My code:

```
tinymce.init({
     selector: "textarea",
     statusbar:false,
     height: 450,
     relative_urls:false,
     browser_spellcheck:true,
     content_css:'<?php echo base_url("css/desktop.css")?>',
     plugins: ['link'],          
     menubar: true,
     toolbar: "bold italic underline strikethrough | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect | link | paste | bullist numlist | outdent indent | blockquote | removeformat | image caption | code",

        });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you also upgrade all plugins to their current versions? Do all plugins you try to load give the same error?

Comment: Thanks @TinyLincoln!  I didn't update the plugins (I do get the error on all of them).  Where do I find the updated plugins?  I don't see anything on this page for link.. https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/link/

Comment: @TinyLincoln, I found the updated plugin from another website of ours using TinyMCE 6 with no problem.  So I copied that over, now the plugin should be up to date and I'm still getting the same error.